# angular js: Unable to validate a textarea

Tags: angularjs, validation, textarea

fellas!

I'm trying to validate a text area upon clicking a link. Thing is, It's not coming inside a form. And when a user clicks a link, content entered in the text area should be posted (saved to database).

I wrote a validation for that. And unfortunately, it's not working and I'm able to make blank posts. I'm trying to prevent blank post posting. I have recreated the form and the controller in a fiddle. Link I'll provide down. but before that, take a look at my html and js code.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myMap">
  <div class="post-textarea" ng-class="{ 'has-error': vm.currentPost.content.$dirty && vm.currentPost.content.$error.required }">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" ng-model="vm.currentPost.content" required></textarea>
    <a ng-click="vm.addPost(vm.currentPost.content,vm.currentPost.$valid)">Clik to Post and validate</a>
  </div>
</div>

JavaScript

angular.module('myApp', [])
  .factory('myService', function($http) {
    var baseUrl = 'api/';
    return {
      postCurrentPost: function(newPost) {
        var dataPost = {
          newPost: newPost
        };
        return $http({
          method: 'post',
          url: baseUrl + 'postCurrentPost',
          data: dataPost,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          }
        });
      }
    };

  })
  .controller('myMap', function(myService, $http, $scope) {

    var vm = this;
    var userObject;

    // Add a post
    vm.addPost = function(newPost, isValid) {
      if (isValid) {
        var currentPost = vm.currentPost;
        currentPost.content = ""; //clear post textarea
        myService.postCurrentPost(newPost).success(function(data) {
          vm.posts = data;
        });
      } else {
        alert('Validation not working');
      }
    };
    //Check validation
    $scope.getError = function(error, name) {
      if (angular.isDefined(error)) {
        if (error.required && name == 'vm.currentPost.content') {
          return "This field is required";
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

And here's a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/iamsajeev/8v6mt2fy/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name of the form input element should be used instead of model value.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myMap">
    <form name="formContent">
      <div class="post-textarea" ng-class="{ 'has-error': formContent.content.$dirty && formContent.content.$error.required }">
      <textarea name='content' class="form-control" rows="3" ng-model="vm.currentPost.content" required></textarea>
      <a ng-click="vm.addPost(vm.currentPost.content,vm.currentPost.$valid)">Clik to Post and validate</a>
      </div>
    </form>
    Content is dirty: {{formContent.content.$dirty}}
    <br>
    Content has required: {{formContent.content.$error.required}}
</div>
```

Comment: Tried that...but it's still not showing the error message. @sawbeanraz

Comment: Please try the code.. that I've added. You need a form or ng-form directive

Comment: No..your code ain't working. I tested it. @sawbeanraz

Comment: I have tried the code in the fiddler you have provided and is working..  May by there's some problem with CSS so its not highlighting..  I have edited the code which display $dirty and $error.required on form.  Please paste the HTML code in the fiddler you have provided.